# Client connections with epoll

Tags: linux, network-programming, sockets, epoll

I'm programming an application(client/server) in C++ for linux using epoll y pthreads but I don't know how to handle the `connect()` calls for attach a new connection in the descriptor list if a loop with `epoll_wait()` is running(Edge-triggered), How to can I do it?... I could to use a dummy file descriptor to trigger an event and scape of wait?, or a simple call to `connect()` could fire the event??...

Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use another file descriptor that's just for waking up your `epoll_wait()` loop.  Use `pipe()` to create the file descriptor.  Add the reading end of the pipe to your `epoll` list, and write a single byte to the writing end when you want to wake it up.  The reading side can just read that byte and discard it.

Comment: Thanks, I will use `pipe()` to old kernel versions and `eventfd()` to new kernel versions(I have found it in man pages.)

adew